# How is memory allocation being done in this C program?

Tags: c, memory-management

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int *a[10];
    a[2] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    a[2][3]=4;
    printf("%d", a[2][3]);
    return 0;

}
```

I have given only the memory equivalent of a single `int` to the pointer variable. How is that I am able to access an element at index `3` for that pointer of a single `int`?

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Use a memory debugger to catch such issues, such as BoundsChecker or Valgrind.

Comment: I am not trying to be a klutz here. I just saw this C code, and didn't know if array bounds checking was even optional for languages, as I was naturally expecting an error.

Comment: @goelakash Everything is optional for languages, basically. :) It's up to the language designers and implementors to shape the semantics of the language (within the bounds of what the computer can do, of course).

Comment: Accessing unallocated memory is a subtle because it will end up in **undefined** behavior.
Your program can:

1. **Crash Immediately** (*in case you request memory that does not belong to your process*)
2. **Temporarily works**
3. **Works perfectly for the next 100 years.**

The final behavior depends on many factors, such as the **combination of compilers/hardware/system**.
You example is very simple and works because you are accessing few bytes out of bounds and this is very likely to be a portion of memory that is reserved (but not allocated) to your process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because nothing is preventing you accessing arrays out of bound and this invokes undefined behavior. Any expected or unexpected behavior of program can be seen.

Answer (score 1):

You can *try* but the behaviour of your program will be *undefined*.

C does not perform that kind of checking at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing some randomly set RAM element. This is a common C programming mistake and is one of the reason for many security flaws.

The [Heartbleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) bug would be a nice example, where people were able to read a good portion of the server RAM, by accessing elements outside of the array structure.